# Simple integral with stochastic Brownian motion integrand

Tags: calculus, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Consider $$\int_0^t \sin(B_s) ds$$

where $B_s$ is standard Brownian motion,

I was wondering can I write

$$\int_0^t \sin(B_s) ds = - ( \cos(B_t) - \cos(B_0)) = - \cos(B_t) ? $$

by using the Calculus fact: 
$$\int \sin(x) dx = -\cos(x) $$

or I should only remain $\int_0^t \sin(B_s) ds$ as the final result?

Comment: @ Chung-Han Hsieh : no it is absolutely wrong that is not the way it works even for standard integral. Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @TheBridge already pointed out, this does **not** work; not even for determinstic "standard" integrals. Please note that the integral

$$\int_0^t \sin(B_s) \,ds \tag{1}$$

is not of the form

$$\int_0^x \sin(y) \, dy.$$

Using Itô's formula you may rewrite $(1)$ as

$$\int_0^t \sin(B_s) \, ds = 2\int_0^t \cos(B_s) \, dB_s - 2 \sin B_t.$$

---

If we consider a stochastic (Itô-)integral with respect to Brownian motion, i.e.

$$\int_0^t f(B_s) \, dB_s$$

for some function $f$, then Itô's formula tells us that we can **not** simply apply the classical rules of integration (e.g. the fundamental theorem of calculus). One of the most-well known examples for this fact is the equality

$$\int_0^t B_s \, dB_s = \frac{1}{2} (B_t^2 - t);$$

from the classical rules we would expect

$$\int_0^t B_s \, dB_s = \frac{B_t^2}{2}.$$

This leads to the so-called Stratonovich integral.

Comment: May I ask how did you derive and rewrite the equation 1? I did not understan d the 2 in both parts. Or which Ito's formula are you using?

Comment: @Creator There is only one Itô's formula for Brownian motion. For 1) just apply Ito's formula to $x \mapsto 2 \sin (x)$ and for 2) consider  $x \mapsto \frac{x^2}{2}$. Don't forget about the $\frac{1}{2}$ in front of the Riemann integral which appears in Itô's formula.

Comment: I still did not get why x goes to 2 sin(x). I still find that x goes to sin(x).

Comment: @Creator Can't tell you anything more without seeing your calculations. Apply Ito's formula to $f(x)=2 \sin(x)$ .... that's it.  If you are stuck with it, then please post your calculations as a comment (... not just the final result, but your whole computations).

Comment: As I understand Ito's formula is $du=u'dx+1/u''(dx)^2$ so if u=sin than x-> sin(x) why 2sin(x)?

Comment: @Creator use $u(x)=2 \sin(x)$ (and in your formula for $du$ there is a $2$ missing, i.e. $\frac{1}{2} u''$ and not $1/u''$)

Comment: It took me a year to understand this. LOL. Now I find it very simple.  Thanks for your help.